# Spring Saml updates?

Tags: spring-saml

I noticed that the release http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-saml/ is using 3.1 versions of spring and security.  Even the example that comes with it is on a pretty old version of spring.

I took the sample and tried to create my own and update the sample code with more recent versions.  Quite a few issues and as well usage of deprecated version of spring security class methods.

Is there any plan afoot to update it to a more recent version of spring/security?

Comment: Yes, I'll bump the versions in Spring SAML 1.1, but no committed schedule as of yet.

Comment: I tried updating the project myself.  Mostly small things.  The only real issue is that you use a deprecated method on a descendant class from LogoutFilter.  You use getFilterProcessesUrl()  which was deprecated in the version you had and finally removed in Spring security 4.  I managed to get it all the way up to Spring 4 on both framework and security.  Only that issue.